# Why is this trigger always displaying?

Tags: sql

I'm already finishing my project for university, and I have 1 trigger that I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FECHASALIDA
BEFORE INSERT ON EXPEDIENTES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.FECHAINGRESO>:NEW.FECHASALIDA)
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20600,:NEW.FECHASALIDA||'No se puede dar una fecha de salida anterior a la del ingreso');
END IF;
END;
```

This triggers is always displaying if I try to create a new case file ( The traduction for "expediente" ) in my website where there is a null departure date
in the form given, and im not really sure why, all I want is that if the departure date ( "Fecha Salida" traduction ) is before entry date ( Bet you already imagine that ), the trigger displays saying "Hi, you just cant do that bro".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This trigger is fired because you use BEFORE INSERT you can use After to fix your issue

Comment: This should be implementing using a `check` constraint, not a trigger.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you please add a tag for the specific SQL dialect you're using, e.g. "PostgreSQL" "MySQL" "SQL Server"

Comment: Tried AFTER insert and didnt work, same for a constraint instead of the trigger, same effect.